# How does Unity call "update()" in the scripts?

Tags: unity, c++, scripting

I understand that you can expose your C++ code to a scripting language such as [ChaiScript](http://chaiscript.com/). From this you can call code that you've made in C++. In Unity, however, they have functions in the script, such as `Update()` that get called. In other words, how do I call script functions from C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripting languages often expose a set of API functions that allow you to inspect and determine attributes about a loaded script, in your case what functions are defined.  This varies by scripting language naturally and will also depend on your native language to scripting language bindings.

In Lua for example, I can load a script and then check whether a particular function is declared.  I've often done this for `Update()` and other methods so that if defined, I create a mapping that will then be invoked during the game simulation for those scripts that have overloaded that callback.

In the case of Unity, their `MonoBehavior` is a contract they've defined and they simply look to see whether you've overwritten specific functions from the contract and if so, then the callback is invoked at the appropriate times during game simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Unity uses its own messaging system to call methods like Update. You can use it as well with for example [Component.SendMessage](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.SendMessage.html).

I think that the underlying implementation of the message system uses some form of reflection to determine what methods a class has and call the appropriate ones.

([This post's answer explains it better](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/177245/how-does-unitys-built-in-event-system-work-behind.html))

Answer (score 0):

`C++` and `C#` can interact quite easily. (In the practice C++ issues relative to name mangling often force to have an intermediate `C` layer)

There are several resources you can have a look such as Mono [P/Invoke docs](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/) and unity docs on [native plugins](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html).

Calling a `C#` function from `C++` code is simply as using a function pointer (a `C#` delegate can be marshalled to be used this way).

---

For what concern how `Unity` handles callbacks it's another question. I don't know the exact underlying implementation but most `MonoBehaviours` hooks like `Update` aren't virtual|abstract method, nor implement any interface.

Why? Not sure, I often asked my self why (honestly I prefer a more explicit approach like implementing an interface like [ISerializationCallbackReceiver](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.html)).

On how the binding between function pointer and C# method happens, it's probably creating a delegate instance. 
The problem is really different between [SendMessage](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html) and `Update`.

I guess Unity is forced to use Reflection for [SendMessage](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html), because the method name is know only at runtime. Use it carefully because reflection is really expensive.

For the others Update, Start, etc.. the problem is simpler because method name, signature and target object are know. So the expensive binding process can be used only once in initialization. Here's a nice [article](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates/).

Comment: If they had implemented their "event methods" as either interfaces or via base class, then you could actually call them yourself through a reference, and these event methods wouldn't be distinguishable from your own public interface. For example: component.LateUpdate() or component.Awake() would be legal. Granted, most Unity devs will make those methods public (like everything else), but they needn't and shouldn't be. At least for virtual methods it's also a matter of performance.